# Exporting multiband Earthpy masked GeoTIFF with Rasterio resulted in original non-masked file

Tags: python, numpy, rasterio, landsat, earthpy

I currently wanted to mask a stacked Landsat 8 GeoTIFF file with the Pixel QA band to remove the clouds and cloud shadows. So far, I have successfully followed the tutorial [here](https://www.earthdatascience.org/courses/use-data-open-source-python/multispectral-remote-sensing/landsat-in-Python/remove-clouds-from-landsat-data/), and have properly plotted the masked scene using a combination of EarthPy and Rasterio. The resulting masked scene is a NumPy masked array.

However when I try to export the clean array as a GeoTIFF file (clean.tif), the resulting file contains the original scene instead of the masked scene file. Below is the code that I have:

```
from rasterio.plot import plotting_extent
import rasterio as rio
import earthpy.plot as ep
import earthpy.mask as em

# Open mask file
with rio.open("mask.tif") as mask_src:
  mask = mask_src.read()
  mask_meta = mask_src.profile

# Open scene file
with rio.open("scene.tif") as scene_src:
  scene = scene_src.read()
  scene_ext = plotting_extent(scene_src)
  scene_trf = scene_src.transform
  scene_meta = scene_src.profile

# Perform masking
clean = em.mask_pixels(scene, mask)

# Print metadata for mask and scene files
print("masked scene shape => " + str(clean.shape))
print("mask meta => " + str(mask_meta))
print("scene meta => " + str(scene_meta))

# Open and write destination tif file
with rio.open("clean.tif", 'w', **scene_meta) as clean_dst:
  clean_dst.write(clean)

# Open destination tif file
with rio.open("clean.tif") as final_dst:
  final = final_dst.read()
  final_ext = plotting_extent(scene_src)

# Plot mask file
ep.plot_bands(mask)
# Plot scene file
ep.plot_rgb(scene, rgb=[4, 3, 2], extent=scene_ext, stretch=True)
# Plot masked scene
ep.plot_rgb(clean, rgb=[4, 3, 2], extent=scene_ext)
# Plot destination tif file
ep.plot_rgb(final, rgb=[4, 3, 2], extent=final_ext, stretch=True)
```

And here are the plots of the files:

1. mask file:
   [image: mask file]
2. scene file:
   [image: scene file]
3. plotted masked array:
   [image: plotted masked array]
4. saved masked array to geotiff:
   [image: saved masked array to geotiff]

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wsxrf4uwq4r0c5q/AAC_jJQo_hgnyLFmCdaHAHPwa?dl=0) is the Dropbox link to the files and the script. Really scratched my head around this, I appreciate any pointers as to what happened and how to fix it. Thank you all:)

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it, I need to supply the NoData value that is taken from the original scene  to the masked array. Here is the fixed script:

```
from rasterio.plot import plotting_extent
import rasterio as rio
import earthpy.plot as ep
import earthpy.mask as em

# Open mask file
with rio.open("mask.tif") as mask_src:
  mask = mask_src.read()
  mask_meta = mask_src.profile

# Open scene file
with rio.open("scene.tif") as scene_src:
  scene = scene_src.read()
  scene_ext = plotting_extent(scene_src)
  scene_trf = scene_src.transform
  scene_meta = scene_src.profile
  scene_nodata = scene_src.nodata

# Perform masking
clean = em.mask_pixels(scene, mask)
clean = clean.filled(scene_nodata)

# Print metadata for mask and scene files
print("masked scene shape => " + str(clean.shape))
print("mask meta => " + str(mask_meta))
print("scene meta => " + str(scene_meta))

# Open and write destination tif file
with rio.open("clean.tif", 'w', **scene_meta) as clean_dst:
  clean_dst.write(clean)

# Open destination tif file
with rio.open("clean.tif") as final_dst:
  final = final_dst.read()
  final_ext = plotting_extent(scene_src)

# Plot mask file
ep.plot_bands(mask)
# Plot scene file
ep.plot_rgb(scene, rgb=[4, 3, 2], extent=scene_ext, stretch=True)
# Plot masked scene
ep.plot_rgb(clean, rgb=[4, 3, 2], extent=scene_ext)
# Plot destination tif file
ep.plot_rgb(final, rgb=[4, 3, 2], extent=final_ext, stretch=True)
```

Hopefully this will be useful for people who are facing the same issue.

Comment: Well done! If this is the correct solution, you should accept it, so other folks know it works and nobody else tries to solve it, and you'll get the points too.